# Why browser calling is not working anymore?

Tags: ringcentral

We're integrating RingCentral for Salesforce on another Dev Org and we used to be able to make calls using a browser but this time it's prompting this error:

> "Your extension is not allowed to make outbound calls with browser currently, please contact your account representative for an upgrade."

This error occurs when changing settings via the RingCentral Utility Bar. Currently, there are 4 items we can choose from (Browser, RingCentral App, RingCentral Phone, & RingOut). The browser should be the default one but like I said there's an error so we can't make calls. Do we need a specific browser extension to make it work or did we miss anything on the setup manual?

We're on Office Premium but I'm not sure if that's an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add free digital line(phone) to your extension to make calls. Without digital line your extension cannot make any outbound call.
To add digital line, you need to add it from your online portal account  http://service.devtest.ringcentral.com
Check the following reference: https://support.ringcentral.com/article/Phone-Numbers-DigitalLine-Overview.html
https://support.ringcentral.com/article/ringcentral-phone-softphone-outbound-calling-adding-digital-line.html